# Creating and managing sublists of STL list

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

I have a solution for a problem and this solution involves the creation of sublists of items (i.e., a subrange) from a STL list of items. For instance, I have a list of integers list and need to create sublist where sublist is a class that represents a range of items from the original list. All ranges are disjoint and I need to perform operations (insert/delete) on the sublists and these changes need to be reflected on the original list.

I have came up with the implementation below, which that uses C++11. However, I am running into trouble when deleting sublists. The problem is that the _end iterator of a sublist points to the _beg pointer of the next consecutive sublist. So my questions are:

1. What is the usual way to represent this pattern? I.e., managing sublists of a list in which modifications in the sublists are reflected in the original list.
2. How can I correct the code below and and still use the *ranged-for* idiom?

In this example the sublists does not do many things but this is just an example. In the original problem the both classes will be used in several different tasks.

Appreciate for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef list<int>           i_list;
typedef list<int>::iterator it_list;

class Sublist {
private:
    string  _name;
    i_list* _items;
    it_list _beg;
    it_list _end;

public:
    Sublist(string name, i_list* items, it_list beg, it_list end) 
        :   _name(name), 
            _items(items),
            _beg(beg), 
            _end(end)
    { 
    }

    it_list begin() { 
        return this->_beg; 
    }

    it_list end() { 
        return this->_end; 
    }

    void erase(it_list it) {
        if (it == _beg) {
            _beg = _items->erase(it);
        }
        else if (it == _end) {
            _end = _items->erase(it);
            _end--;
        }
        else { 
            _items->erase(it);
        }
    }

    void print() {
        cout << _name << ":" << endl;

        // this for access an invalid iterator
        for (auto x : *this) {
            cout << "\t" << x << endl;
        }
    }
};

class List {
private:
    i_list* items;

public:
    List(int size) { 
        items = new i_list();

        for (int i=1; i<=size; i++)
            items->push_back(i*10);
    }

    Sublist* sl(string name, int beg, int end) {
        return new Sublist( name, items, 
                                find(items->begin(), items->end(), beg),
                                find(items->begin(), items->end(), end));
    }
};


int main() {
    List f(20);

    Sublist* sl1 = f.sl("SL1", 10, 60);
    Sublist* sl2 = f.sl("SL2", 60, 110);
    Sublist* sl3 = f.sl("SL3", 110, 160);
    Sublist* sl4 = f.sl("SL4", 160, 210);

    sl1->print();
    sl2->print();
    sl3->print();
    sl4->print();

    sl2->erase( sl2->begin() );
    sl2->erase( sl2->begin() );
    sl2->erase( sl2->begin() );
    sl2->erase( sl2->begin() );
    sl2->erase( sl2->begin() );

    // When uncommented the program will get stuck looping
    //sl1->print();
    sl2->print();
    sl3->print();
    sl4->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I just replaced the creation of Sublist* in the List::sl method to a new list<int>(begin...end) and it worked. But why does it work? I thought that in this way the elements would be duplicated and changes in the sublist would not be reflected in the original list...

Comment: where do you check, whether your changes are reflected in the original list?

Comment: Can you show your changed code?

Comment: @CaptainOblivious: that will in the worst case replace an N-element list by its 2^N-element power-set and thus might be inconvenient

Comment: @JohnTortugo: there is no need to use an `ilist* items= new ilist()` in your class. Just use an `ilist items`.

Comment: @MikeMB: I guess I was too sleepy and sloppy and did not see that changes aren't being reflected in the original list.

Comment: @davidhigh: I did not understood what you meant by `ilist items`. Care to explain?

Comment: Your class `List` owns the `i_list`, so it is perfectly fine to write `i_list item`. In contrast, if you use `i_list *item = new i_list()`, you enter manual memory management which involves several constraints (such as the rule of three). If you cannot avoid the pointer, I suggest you use `std::unique_ptr` instead. But all that is not really related to your question...

Comment: Ok Sure! I used `i_list*` because I wanted to let Sublist change the items. In the real code both classes uses `shared_ptr`. What are these three rules you are talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you treat `end` as part of the range. See e.g. `erase` which will acccept `end`. **In C++, `end` is the first element not part of the range**. Thus for adjacent sublist, `end` is trivially equal to the next `begin`.

The ranged-for idiom will not access `*end` for this reason.

Comment: I see that erase receiving an `end` pointer is a problem. But right now what I am trying to solve is what happens after erase deletes a `begin` iterator. Because when that happens the previous sublist `end` iterator becomes invalid. Could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: Fair point. It may be a valid implementation to store the penultimate iterator internally (closed range) and return `std::next(penultimate)` from  `.end()`. This has one big potential problem: empty subranges would have `begin==end`. Is this a complication for you?

Comment: I think that might work but to where should I point begin and end when a sublist is empty? If they point to a item of a different sublist this seems ugly to me. I guess using a sentinel value in each sublist would be a reasonable way to solve this problem..

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when the sublist becomes empty, thus the `_end` iterator is invalid, we cannot use `_end` or `end()` anymore. I managed to introduce a flag to when the list is empty and thus your suggestion worked too.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>First of all, your program doesn't compile and has a few logic errors, so I'm not sure, whether I'm addressing your actual problem, or just a typo.</strike>

However, your claim that

> All ranges are disjoint

is semantically not true, as you access some elements (namely the ones pointed to by <strike>begin and end</strike> `_begin` and `_end` iterators) via two different sublists. In case of STL containers, `C::end()` is not <strike>supposed</strike> required to point to an actual element and erasing or dereferencing the iterator is undefined behavior.

What I'd do in your case is

1) introduce a separate flag to indicate, that the sublist is empty

```
 private:
    string  _name;
    i_list* _items;
    bool _isEmpty;
    it_list _beg;
    it_list _end;
```

2) point _end to the last "valid" element and implement `end()` the following way

```
Sublist(string name, i_list* items, it_list beg, it_list end) 
    :   _name(name), 
        _items(items),
        _isEmpty(beg==end),
        _beg(beg),             
        _end(beg==end ? beg : end-1)
{ 
}

it_list end() {
    if (this->_isEmpty) {
        return this->_begin;   
    } else {    
         return this->_end+1; 
    }
}
```

3) Check in `erase()`, whether the user is trying to erase the last element in the range

```
void erase(it_list it) {      
    if (it == _beg) {
        if (_beg==_end) {
            _isEmpty=true;                
        }
        _beg = _items->erase(it);
    }
    else if (it == _end) { //This would be UB in the original version anyway
        _end = _items->erase(it);
        _end--;
    }
    else { 
        _items->erase(it);
    }
}
```

4) Adapt your `insert` method accordingly (if you have one)

Erasing an element from an already empty range is - I believe - usually UB anyway, so I didn't check for that, but you could of course add this check at the beginning of erase and throw an error.

==============

EDIT:

There is still one problem with my solution:
A copy of sl1->end() is still invalidated by a call to `sl2->erase( sl2->begin() )`, but I believe, the only way to fix this is to either introduce a costume iterator or modify the original data structure in some way - e.g. splice some extra guard nodes into the original list

As a response to MSalters' comment I would like to elaborate a bit more on what I percieve as the problem:
Depending on whether one focuses on the implementation or on the behavior - and ignoring empty sublists all together - you can see it either as a single design error or one certain and one potential error in the behavior. Let's start with the last one:

As there is no separate documentation, one could say that the code of `Sublist::erase()` implies that `sl1->erase( sl1->end() )` should work, but as it corrupts sl2 there is a defect. However, one could also argue that - expecting STL container semantics - this call is UB anyway and thus, the class behaves "correctly" as corrupting sl2 is just a possible incarnation of UB.
The bigger Problem, which the example code in `main()` actually runs into, is that the call `sl2->erase( sl2->begin() )` corrupts `sl1` and I believe no one would say that this is acceptable behavior.

Now, both of these errors in the behavior are a consequence of a single design problem, namely that the `_begin` and `_end` iterators of adjacent sublists point to the same NODE in the parent list *without knowing about each other*. The fact that the returned iterators from `sl1.end()` and `sl2.begin()` are pointing to the same memory location is not necessarily a problem in itself, but when `sl2->erase( sl2->begin() )` is called, this does not only destroy the element which `_end` points to, but also severs the link leading to that node. As a result, the range based for loop never reaches `sl1.end()` and as this linked lists seems to be implemented as a circular list, it results in an endless loop.

Comment: "[elements] pointed to by begin and end iterators" - End iterators do not point to elements of the range. C++, like C, uses half-open intervals: `[begin, end)`. That is precisely why it is OK for adjacent ranges to share their end/begin iterator.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, but for one, - as you pointed out yourself - the semantics of the code imply that end() IS considered part of the subrange. And second, I was refering to the internal iterators _end and _begin. For a linked list it IS a Problem, if they point to the same element, even if end() is never dereferenced or deleted directly, as modifying the start or end of one sublist invalidates the according iterator stored in the adjecent one (hidden shared state). I'll modify my answer to elaborate a bit more on that point when I have time.

Comment: @MikeMB: Here the code compiles nicely when I use g++ with -std=c++11. What errors did you get? The point of the list not "begin disjoint" in this code is exactly the problem that I want to solve. If there are other 'errors' in the code they aren't what I asked for help and probably I did not care to handle them before the "erase problem" is solved. Could you post the implementation that you are suggesting that still uses the `ranged-for idiom` as I asked in the question? Thanks!

Comment: I see that you have edited you answer to include some explanation.. and texts from the comments. That is OK. But a funny part is, my question is exactly asking for a solution for what your 'solution' does not work (your words): "A copy of sl1->end() is still invalidated by a call to sl2->erase( sl2->begin() ), ...". As a matter of fact I have introduced a sentinel value after each sublist so that the _end of each sublist points to this sentinel.

Comment: @JohnTortugo: In short, I think I answered prematurely, before I properly understood your code and question. My sincerest appologies for that. The reason, why I think that my answer solves your problem is that your example code in main should work flawlessly and you can use the range based for loop, except for cases, where you e.g. delete the first element of sl2 while traversing sl1. Also at any point in time, you can correctly retrieve the current end position of your sublist, which was not possible before, you just can not cache it under all circumstances.